# How to use the Adafruit_BBIO module with python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to use the GPIO pins on a Beaglebone Black. I've used the `Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO` module when trying some code examples from a book.
Since then I coded my whole logic in python3, which can't access the module. 
I would like to ask if someone knows how to access the module with python3.
I already tried to copy the Adafruit_BBIO directory into my python3 folder but it didn't work.

```
'#!/usr/bin/python3
import Adafruit_BBIO'
```

When I call the mainscript like

```
root@arm: python3 main.py
```

I get this error:

```
_Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 8, in <module> import lcd_control File "/home/debian/python/lcd_control.py", line 3, in <module> import Adafuit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO ImportError: No module named 'Adafuit_BBIO'_
```

Comment: Please show the code if possible, it will be convenient for us.

Comment: The error comes right when I import the module
'import Adafruit_BBIO'
root@arm:/home/debian/python# python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import lcd_control
  File "/home/debian/python/lcd_control.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Adafuit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named 'Adafuit_BBIO'

And this is the output i get

Comment: sorry for my bad formatting :3

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information instead writing in comments!

Comment: Try this `import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO`

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to figure out your gpio by going to

```
$ ls /sys/class/gpio/gpio100 ;or whatever your gpiopin is
```

then in python

```
class SimpleGPIO:
     def __init__(self,gpio_pin):
        self.gpio_pin = gpio_pin
        self.gpio_path = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/"%gpio_pin
        with open(self.gpio_path+"direction") as f:
        self.direction = f.read()
     def write(self,value):
        if self.direction != "out":
           os.system("echo out > %sdirection"%self.gpio_path)
           self.direction = "out"
        os.system("echo %s > %svalue"%(value,self.gpio_path)
     def read(self):
        if self.direction != "in":
           os.system("echo in > %sdirection"%self.gpio_path)
           self.direction = "in"
        with open(self.gpio_path+value) as f:
           return f.read()


 gpio_100 = SimpleGPIO(100) #open on 100
 gpio_100.write(1)
```

Comment: In my /usr/class/gpio/ there are four folders, gpiochip0, 32, 64 and gpiochip96. Each of them contains
'base  label  ngpio  power  subsystem  uevent'

Comment: it might be somewhere else ... just google access gpio through filesystem on raspberry py

Comment: this tutorial might help with the filesystem parts ... https://sites.google.com/site/semilleroadt/raspberry-pi-tutorials/gpio

Answer (score 1):

Awesome! thanks Joran, this has been a huge help. Your code didn't work for me at first, I had to make a few tweaks: this is what I use now and import into other  simple programs to use GPIO:

```
  import os 
  class SimpleGPIO:
      def __init__(self,gpio_pin):
          self.gpio_pin = gpio_pin
          os.system("echo %d > /sys/class/gpio/export" % self.gpio_pin)
          self.gpio_path = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/"%gpio_pin
          with open(self.gpio_path+"direction") as f:
              self.direction = f.read()
      def write(self,value):
          if self.direction != "out":
              os.system("echo out > %sdirection"%self.gpio_path)
              self.direction = "out"
          os.system("echo %s > %svalue"%(value,self.gpio_path))
      def read(self):
          if self.direction != "in":
              os.system("echo in > %sdirection"%self.gpio_path)
              self.direction = "in"
          with open(self.gpio_path+value) as f:
              return f.read()
```

now, I just reuse the code by adding `from gpio import SimpleGPIO` at the beginning.

I found when i pasted it into this post, it seemed to remove the same line that was missing from yours, `import os` and `os.system("echo %d > /sys/class/gpio/export.....` I'm guessing it did the same when you posted which is why it didn't work straight away for me.

Thanks a bunch! I really didn't like having to use the `Adafruit` module since it didn't work for `python3` directly plus i learned a ton about how to use the `GPIO` just by working through this and getting the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring this question up-to-date, the following now works to install Adafruit_GPIO for python3 in Debian "buster":

```
pip3 install Adafruit-GPIO
```

Looking at the [project history](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/), they made updates to be compatible with Python 3 in April 2019.